# Excel - Create item list from table values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of tools that are currently on our construction sites with how many of each tool is on each site which looks something like this:

[image: Item Table]

I'm trying to create a formula that will list the tools that are on the site and skip those that aren't with the quantity listed next to the tool. I tried creating a drop down list of the top row that will determine which column the formula looks down - seemed simple enough on paper but I'm struggling to put it into practice.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A pivot table could do all you want.

Comment: @Eric.O do you prefer VBA code?

Comment: Show what have you tried and where you have run into trouble.  A drop-down list and index/match formulas is one method. By the way, your screenshot virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter it is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald never used one of those before - just looked into it and it works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to complete your task with VBA code try:

```
Sub test2()

    Dim i As Long, LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, j As Long, AddCol As Long, LastRowNew As Long
    Dim SiteName As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        AddCol = 3

        For i = 3 To LastCol

            .Cells(1, LastCol + AddCol).Value = .Cells(1, i).Value

            For j = 2 To LastRow
                If .Cells(j, i).Value <> 0 Then
                    LastRowNew = .Cells(.Rows.Count, (LastCol + AddCol)).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(LastRowNew + 1, LastCol + AddCol).Value = .Cells(j, i).Value
                    .Cells(LastRowNew + 1, (LastCol + AddCol) - 1).Value = .Cells(j, 2).Value
                End If

            Next j

            AddCol = AddCol + 3

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]